# How to avoid runtime errors when accessing PageSetup property

Tags: excel, page-setup, vba

Hi everyone I have a small question. I'm currently working on an excel program that will generate reports, format them and print them. I was trying to show my boss the program when excel gave me an error saying pagesetup class was not working (error 1004). It took me a few minutes to realise that the problem was with her printer. The second I changed her printer it worked fine.

My question is how would you gurus go about to make sure that the run time error wouldn't appear when I send my excel file across the company where I have no control over what printer they have installed?

I don't mind not being able to print from excel but I do need it to be formatted in excel for them.

Thanks a lot guys.

Comment: Excel 2010 version:14.06112.5000 (32-bit)

Comment: Try setting `Application.PrintCommunication = False` before accessing PageSetup. http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Excel-2010-Communicate-cad0ff38

Comment: Is that error came from Windows or from Excel? Check the error dialog title. A screenshot would help if can't determine where it actually came from.

Comment: The error comes from Excel itself. Sadly I've been waiting for the person who got the error to come back but they haven't so I can't replicate the error to check if application.printcommunication = false would work. Thanks guys for the help.